# Replace "img" in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am writing a "plugin" where I can replace news data on my homesite without reloading it.
I click the news I want and it will load in a bigger area of the page. 
Everything works except the picture. I don't know why, but it won't replace it.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="col1-2">   
            <div class="box orange">
                <div class="lb"><div class="rb">
                <div class="bb"><div class="blc">
                <div class="brc"><div class="tb">
                <div class="tlc"><div class="trc">

                <div class="content">
                    <div class="box-content">
                        <div class="reisen">
                            <div class="infos"> 
                                <img class="home__image" src="http://placehold.it/500x275">                         
                            </div>



                            <div class="text">
                                <a class="home__headline" href="galerie_detail.html"><h1>Lady Salsa Festival 2012</h1></a></p>
                                <p><h2 class="home__date">01. - 03. Juni 2012</h2></p>
                                <p class="home__text">Sals Paradies in Saarbrücken! Bereits zum 8. Mal fand das Salsa-Paradies statt welches als Großevent in der Region Saarbrücken Salseros aus Frankreich, Luxemburg und Deutschland anzieht! Diesmal waren wieder einige Top-Stars aus der Salsa-Szene zu Gast. Die Vize-Weltmeister 2009 Anne und Anichi, die Könige des kubansichen Son, Mario & Madeline sowie aus Paris Lia & Leo eines der besten kubanischen Tanzpaare Europas.</p>                                                           
                            </div>

                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                </div>



                <div class="content">
        <ul class="news__list">
            <ul class="home__list">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/238x131"><h1>Marvin Ramos & Kristin </h1></a><h2>01. - 0f3. Juni 2012</h2><p hidden>Salsa Paradies in Saarbrücken! Bereits zum 8. Mal fand das Salsa-Paradies statt welches als Großevent in der Region Saarbrücken Salseros aus Frankreich, Luxemburg und Deutschland anzieht! Diesmal waren wieder einige Top-Stars aus der Salsa-Szene zu Gast. Die Vize-Weltmeister 2009 Anne und Anichi, die Könige des kubansichen Son, Mario & Madeline sowie aus Paris Lia & Leo eines der besten kubanischen Tanzpaare Europas.</p> </li></ul>
```

Jquery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var clicktarget = $(".home__list a"); // Klick-Auslöser
    var hometarget = $(".home__player"); // Container
    var homehead = $(".home__headline"); // Headline
    var homedate = $(".home__date");
    var hometext = $(".home__text");
    var homeimage = $(".home__image");

    $(clicktarget).on("click", function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass("current")){
            return false;
        } else {
            $(clicktarget).removeClass("current"); // entfernt ".current"-Class von allen Elementen
            $(this).addClass("current"); // setzt ".current"-Class

            var homeheadline = $(this).closest("li").find("h1").html();
            $(homehead).html(homeheadline);

            var homenewsdate = $(this).closest("li").find("h2").html();
            $(homedate).html(homenewsdate);

            var homenewstext = $(this).closest("li").find("p").html();
            $(hometext).html(homenewstext);

            var homenewsimage = $(this).closest("li").find("img").html();
            $(homeimage).html(homenewsimage);

            $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$("#video-top").offset().top}, 500);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just an FYI: Your vars at the top (`clicktarget `,`hometarget` etc) are already jQuery objects so no need to wrap them again in `$(..)` lower down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery's `.attr()` method instead. You are trying to edit the html inside the  tag which is non-existant. Instead, try `$(homeimage).attr("src","http://mynextimage.png");`

Comment: yeah this somehow works, but i dont want to type in the src of the picture manually. i want it to automatically read out the <img src="http://placehold.it/238x131">

Comment: Can't you make your `homenewsimage` variable be the src for the image rather than the entire HTML tag? If so, this would work just as well, otherwise you'll just have to use a bit more javascript to abstract the text between double quotes from your `homenewsimage` before then making that the src.

Comment: i´m really stuck somehow, at the moment i absolutly dont get it.
i tried this now 

var homenewsimage = $(this).closest("li").find("img").html();
    $(homeimage).attr("src", $(homenewsimage));

but it wont work

Comment: `var homenewsimage = $(this).closest("li").find("img").attr("src"); $(homeimage).attr("src", homenewsimage);` should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
var homenewsimage_url = $(this).closest("li").find("img").attr('src');
$(homeimage).html('<img src="'+homenewsimage_url+'"/>');
```

Easy to get the image `src` and put like image html with that `src`

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way should be $(homeimage).src("http://example.com/image.jpg");